# Create a read only excel file from SSIS?

Tags: ssis

Is there a way to create a read only excel file from SSIS?

Comment: There are two different things you could be referring to: the file system supports the concept of a readonly file. Excel the application allows for the definition of worksheets to be reaonly. Which one are going for?

Answer (score 1):

That's a filesystem concern, not an SSIS one. Any file that SSIS creates will be owned by the user SSIS runs as. The best solution would be to set the ACL on the target folder to be what you want; when SSIS creates the file it will get those permissions by default.

If you can't do that for some operational reason, you can manipulate the file after creation with a command task. You can use SetACL or any command line tools for this.

Comment: I should add that the second case does expose the file briefly until the command task runs. If security is essential, that may not be acceptable.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to accomplish this with a File System Task.
Here's the info from MSDN:
The File System task performs operations on files and directories in the file system. For example, by using the File System task, a package can create, move, or delete directories and files. You can also use the File System task to set attributes on files and directories. For example, **the File System task can make files hidden or read-only.**